# Finding Units in a subring of $ \mathbb Q\ $

Tags: ring-theory

Consider the set 
$$R= \left\{\frac{n}{3^k}: n\in\mathbb{Z}\mbox{ and }k\in\mathbb{N}\right\}$$

which is a subring of the rational numbers, $\mathbb{Q}.$ Find the units in this ring $R$.

I wanna think simple like $\text{gcd}(n,k)=1$.

Comment: In the integers, the only units are $\pm 1$.  Which other numbers become invertible within $R$?

Comment: I got confused with the definition of $R$. Should it be $$R=\{\frac{n}{3^k}:n\in\mathbb{Z} \mbox{ and  }k\in\mathbb{N}\}?$$

Comment: I got to edit your question.:)

Comment: Approved jun's edit. The only way the description of the ring makes sense. Faust7: If you prefer the description of $R$ to be *inline* (immersed within regular text) as opposed *displayed* (centered on a line of its own), alert me, jun or edit it yourself!

Comment: Lol im more then fine with that =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In $\mathbb{Q}$, the inverse of $\pm {a \over b}$ is $\pm {b \over a}$. Because in $R$ the denominator must be a power of $3$, to have both $a \over b$ and $b \over a$ in $R$, you must have $a = 3^x$ and $b = 3^y$. Therefore the units are $\pm 3^{x-y} = \pm 3^z$ where $z \in \mathbb{Z}$.